# Jenkins and Nexus: How to upload javadoc and sources?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, nexus3

I am using Jenkins to build my artifacts and to upload them to my Nexus. While this works fine with the artifact itself, I am unable to upload both the jars containing the sources and the javadoc. Trying to results in a BadRequest from my Nexus.

Javadoc and sources are generated by maven-sources-plugin and maven-javadoc-plugin.

I am using "Nexus Repository Manager Publisher" to upload the artifact. In this case all artifacts will be uploaded to maven-releases (for test cases I made sure that release artifacts may be overriden. After I am able to upload javadoc and sources, this setting will be reset to default)

Can anyone help me here?
How do I configure a build step in Jenkins to upload javadoc and sources to the nexus.

Comment: Please show the steps you are using to upload the sources/javadocs etc. and how you do the rest?

Comment: can you post your pom/are you setting the classifiers correctly?

Comment: Have you attached them to the artifact itself?